# Cant Install anything on Ubuntu 12.04 after power failure

Tags: 12.04, installation, software-center

I was installing Google Earth from a package, and my power went out in mid-way. 
When I power on my computer a pop up comes saying system problem detected. Now I cannot install ANYTHING, no updates, missing plugins, open up software center, nothing.

In the notification area an error message comes stating the following:

> An error occurred, Please run package manager from the right click
>   menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.

The error message was:

> 'Unknown Error:'(lessthansign)type'Exceptions.SystemError'>' (E: The
>   package google-earth-stable:i386 needs to be re installed, but I can't
>   find an archive for it.)This usually means that your installed package
>   have unmet dependencies

I am really up set: here are the technical details:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In a terminal window, (   will open one for you) type

```
 sudo apt-get -f update
```

You will be asked for your password.  When that's done, type

```
`sudo apt-get -f upgrade`.
```

You won't be asked for your password. Watch for error messages. Let us know if that solves it.